# How do I show the probability of independent events is a content?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm referencing this example from pg. 19 of Klenke's *Probability theory a comprehensive course*. I've paraphrased the example to make it shorter:

> Example 1.40 (product measure, Bernoulli measure) Let $E$ be a finite set of possible outcomes, and for $e\in E$, let $p_e\geq0$ be the probability that $e$ occurs, hence $\sum_{e\in E}p_e = 1$. For a fixed realization of the repeated experiment, let $\omega_1, \omega_2, \ldots\in E$ be the observed outcomes. Hence the space of *all* possible outcomes of the repeated experiment is $\Omega = E^\mathbb{N}$. Define the set of all sequences whose first $n$ values are $\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n$ as $$[\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n]:=\{\omega'\in\Omega:\textrm{$\omega_i'=\omega_i$ for any $i = 1, \ldots, n$}\}.$$ Let $\mathcal{A}_0 = \{\emptyset\}$. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define the class of cylinder sets that depend only on the first $n$ coordinates, $$\mathcal{A}_n:=\{[\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n]:\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n\in E\},$$ and let $\mathcal{A}:=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\mathcal{A}_n$. Then for any choice $\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n\in E$ the probability of the event $[\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n]$ is the product of the probabilities of the individual events; that is, $$\mu([\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n])=\prod_{i=1}^np_{\omega_i}.$$ Then $\mu$ is a content on the semiring $\mathcal{A}$.

It's left as an exercise to prove the claim. So I want to prove that $\mu$ is a content on the semiring $\mathcal{A}$.

I've already proven that $\mathcal{A}$ was a semiring. As a result, I know that for distinct elements $A, B\in\mathcal{A}$, we have $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $A\subset B$, or $B\subset A$.

I want to prove that $\mu$ is additive on $\mathcal{A}$ (i.e. $\mu(\biguplus_{i=1}^nA_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_i)$ for finite disjoint $A_1, \ldots, A_n\in\mathcal{A}$, such that $\biguplus_{i=1}^nA_i = A\in\mathcal{A}$), hence is a content. Let $A, A_1, \ldots, A_m\in\mathcal{A}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $A = \biguplus_{i=1}^mA_i = [\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n]\in\mathcal{A}_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha_i\in E$ for every $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Then, I want to show that $\mu(A) = \sum_{i=1}^m\mu(A_m)$.

My thought was to do an induction proof on $n$. However, that still feels very messy to me. For example, if the observed outcomes are $\{0, 1\}$, then an example set $[0]$ could be written as union of disjoint sets of various sizes, $$[0] = [0, 0]\cup[0, 1] = [0, 0]\cup[0, 1, 0]\cup[0, 1, 1],$$ which complicates my proof, and suggests that I might need to do an induction within this induction. But I'm hesitant to do that.

Even considering very simple cases: if $A_i = [\alpha_1^i, \ldots, \alpha_{n+1}^i]\in\mathcal{A}_{n+1}$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, m$, then $$\sum_{i=1}^m\mu(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^m\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}p_{\alpha_j^i} = \sum_{i=1}^m\prod_{j=1}^np_{\alpha_j}p_{\alpha_{n+1}^i} = \mu(A)\sum_{\alpha_{n+1}^i\in E}p_{\alpha_{n+1}^i} = \mu(A),$$ but this is only one case.

Is there a more straightforward way to prove this? Or am I being too lazy, and I should just do some kind of nested induction and expect the proof to be several pages long?

Comment: "...is a *content*"?  Please explain.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork a content is a set function $\mu:\mathcal{A}\to[0, \infty]$ on semiring $\mathcal{A}$ where $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ that $\mu$ is additive. That is, for every $A, A_1, \ldots, A_n\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $A = \biguplus_{i=1}^nA_i$, then $\mu(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A_n)$.

Comment: Huh.  Never heard of it, and it isn't in my ***A book of set theory*** by Charles C. Pinter, couldn't find it on Wikipedia, etc.  So I guess I learned something!

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This is an horrific proof. I **think** that I more or less understand how to prove that $\mu$ is a content, but it's very finicky and the notation is a bear. I may well have made errors below.*

*Also, I use Klenke's notation.*

---

We want to show that $\mu$ is a content on the semiring $\mathcal{A}$, which really only involves showing that $\mu$ is additive. To do that, we need to determine what form disjoint sets $A_1, \dots, A_m \in \mathcal{A}$, with $\bigcup_{i = 1}^m A_i \in \mathcal{A}$ would take. Because everything in $\mathcal{A}$ is of the form $[\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n]$, we need to choose $A_1, \dots, A_m$ such that they're disjoint and their union takes the form $[\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n]$. If $\# E = N$ and $e_1, \dots, e_N \in E$, then one way this could happen would be if $B_1 = [\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n, e_1], \dots, B_N = [\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n, e_N]$. If we had such $B_1, \dots, B_N$, then

\begin{align}
    \begin{split}\label{eq:1.40}
        \sum_{i = 1}^N \mu(B_i) &= \sum_{i = 1}^N \left( \prod_{j = 1}^n p_{\omega_j} \cdot p_{e_i} \right)\\
        &= \prod_{j = 1}^n p_{\omega_j} \underbrace{\sum_{i = 1}^N p_{e_i}}_{=1}\\
        &= \mu\bigl([\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n]\bigr)\\
        &= \mu\left(\biguplus_{i = 1}^N B_i\right)
    \end{split}
\end{align}

However, other ways of partitioning $[\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n]$ are also possible. Let us try to imagine what all possible ways of partitioning $[\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n]$ can look like.

Here is a specific example. Say $E = \{0, 1\}$, and we want to partition $[0]$. We can let $B_1 = [0, 0]$ and $B_2 = [0, 1]$. This is a partition of $[0]$. Let $A_1 = [0, 1], A_2 = [0, 0, 1]$ and $A_3 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]$. These sets are disjoint, but they do not form a partition of $[0]$. We would need to add more sets in order to partition $[0]$. We could have something like

\begin{align*}
        A_1 &= [0, 1]\\
        A_2 &= [0, 0, 1]\\
        A_3 &= [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]\\
        A_4 &= [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]\\
        A_5 &= [0, 0, 0, 0]
\end{align*}

These sets partition $[0]$. We have

\begin{align*}
        [0] &= [0, 0] \uplus [0, 1]\\
        &= \underbrace{[0, 0, 0] \uplus [0, 0, 1]}_{=[0, 0]} \uplus [0, 1]\\
        &= \underbrace{[0, 0, 0, 0] \uplus [0, 0, 0, 1]}_{=[0, 0, 0]} \uplus [0, 0, 1] \uplus [0, 1]\\
        &= [0, 0, 0, 0] \uplus \underbrace{[0, 0, 0, 1, 0] \uplus [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]}_{=[ 0, 0, 0, 1]} \uplus [0, 0, 1] \uplus [0, 1]\\
        &= \underbrace{A_5 \uplus A_3 \uplus A_4 \uplus A_2}_{=B_1} \uplus \underbrace{A_1}_{=B_2}
\end{align*}

To be clear, all the sets in every line are disjoint.

This example suggests what a general partition $A_1, \dots, A_m$ of $[\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n]$ can look like. Say we have such a partition, and that the set of the lengths of the sets of the partition (meaning the number of outcomes they hold fixed) is $L \subset \mathbb{N}$ where $n < \min L \leq \max L = n + k$. Thus, $L$ is some collection of numbers between $n + 1$ and $n + k$, inclusive. The set $L$ has to include sets of all lengths $\min L, \min L + 1, \dots, \max L$, otherwise it wouldn't form a partition of $[\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n]$.

Thus, the work shown in Equations \ref{eq:1.40} can be applied repeatedly. The sets $A_1, \dots, A_m$ must contain $N$ sets of length $\max L$. To see this, note that if there is a longest set in $A_1, \dots, A_m$ that has the form $[\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n, \dots, \omega_{\max L - 1}, \omega_{\max L}]$, then there must be $N - 1$ other sets among $A_1, \dots, A_m$ that are the same as the longest set in positions $1, \dots, \max L - 1$, but in position $\max L$, they exhaust all other choices of $N - 1$ remaining elements of $E$. Otherwise, we wouldn't have all of $[\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n, \dots, \omega_{\max L - 1}]$. Therefore, some subset (meaning a selection) of the sets $A_1, \dots, A_m$ partition $[\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n, \dots, \omega_{\max L - 1}]$. Say the indices of that selection of sets belong to the set $I^{\max L} \subset \{ 1, \dots, m \}$, and define $A^{\max L} = \biguplus_{i \in I^{\max L}} A_i = [\omega_1, \dots, \omega_n, \dots, \omega_{\max L - 1}]$. Note that Equations \ref{eq:1.40} imply that $\mu$ is additive over $A^{\max L}$:

\begin{equation}
        \sum_{i \in I^{\max L}} \mu(A_i) = \mu\left(\biguplus_{i \in I^{\max L}} A_i \right)
\end{equation}

Now, in the collection $A_1, \dots, A_m$, temporarily replace the sets with indices belonging to $I^{\max L}$ with $A^{\max L}$. Our longest set in the collection now has length $\max L - 1$. By the same logic as before, there must in fact be $N$ sets of length $\max L - 1$, and these can similarly be grouped into the set $A^{\max L - 1} = \biguplus_{i \in I^{\max L - 1}} A_i$, which has length $\max L - 2$. Note that $A^{\max L}$ will be assimilated into $A^{\max L - 1}$, meaning that $I^{\max L - 1} \supset I^{\max L}$, and $\mu$ is again additive over the disjoint union comprising $A^{\max L - 1}$, because

\begin{align*}
        \sum_{i \in I^{\max L - 1}} \mu(A_i) &= \sum_{\substack{i \in I^{\max L - 1} \\ \setminus I^{\max L}}} \mu(A_i) + \sum_{i \in I^{\max L}} \mu(A_i)\\
        &= \underbrace{\sum_{\substack{i \in I^{\max L - 1} \\ \setminus I^{\max L}}} \mu(A_i) + \mu\Biggl(\underbrace{\biguplus_{i \in I^{\max L}} A_i}_{=A^{\max L}}\Biggr)}_{\substack{\text{sets } A_i \text{, } i \in I^{\max L - 1} \text{, } A^{\max L} \text{ are a} \\ \text{partition of a set of length } \max L - 2 \\ \text{in terms of sets of length } \max L - 1}}\\
        &= \mu\left(\biguplus_{i \in I^{\max L - 1}} A_i \right)
\end{align*}

Continuing in this way, we eventually condense $A_1, \dots, A_m$ into $B_1, \dots, B_N$. We can now partition the sum $\sum_{i = 1}^m \mu(A_i)$ according to the lengths of the sets:

\begin{align*}
        \sum_{i = 1}^m \mu(A_i) &= \sum_{i \notin I^{\max L}} \mu(A_i) + \sum_{i \in I^{\max L}} \mu(A_i)\\
        &= \sum_{i \notin I^{\max L - 1}} \mu(A_i) + \sum_{\substack{i \in I^{\max L - 1} \\ \notin I^{\max L}}} \mu(A_i) + \mu\left(\biguplus_{i \in I^{\max L}} A_i\right)\\
        &= \sum_{i \notin I^{\max L - 2}} \mu(A_i) + \sum_{\substack{i \in I^{\max L - 2} \\ \notin I^{\max L - 1}}} \mu(A_i) + \mu\left(\biguplus_{i \in I^{\max L - 1}} A_i\right)\\
        &\vdots\\
        &= \sum_{i \notin I^{n + 2}} \mu(A_i) + \sum_{\substack{i \in I^{n + 2} \\ \notin I^{n + 3}}} \mu(A_i) + \mu\left(\biguplus_{i \in I^{n + 3}} A_i\right)\\
        &= \sum_{i \notin I^{n + 2}} \mu(A_i) + \mu\left(\biguplus_{i \in I^{n + 2}} A_i\right)\\
        &= \mu\left(\biguplus_{i = 1}^m A_i\right)
\end{align*}

We conclude that $\mu$ is a content.